# Select Multiple Columns From deffrent Table to new table using procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a new table named `tmp_jobdetails` having columns

```
CMP_CODE,PRN_CODE ,PRN_NAME,PRN_DATE,SITECODE,LOCATIONCODE, JOB_NO,PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME,QTY_AVL
```

I want to create a procedure `sp_detdetails` for inserting the columns from  other three tables `ms-product`,`tt_stkled`,`ms_principle`

`ms_principle` have the columns `PRN_CODE ,PRN_NAME`

`tt_stkled` have`CMP_CODE,PRN_CODE,JOB_NO,PRN_DTAE,QTY_AVL,SITECODE,LOCATIONCODE`

and `ms_product` have the columns `PRN_CODE,PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME`

these three table's fields are to be inserted into the table `tmp_jobdetails`.

how I make it through a procedure. I want to call the procedure by range of `PRN_DATE`  , the date is a field in the table `tmp_jobdetails`.

Comment: please provide more information and some sample data with the expected output. also, i'm guessing you aren't using `sql-server`, `mysql` and `oracle`, so please select only the relevant tags.

Comment: I just generally assigned my columns names to make less time spent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  CREATE TABLE tmp_jobdetails
(
    cmp_code        INTEGER
  , prn_code        INTEGER
  , prn_name        VARCHAR2 (10)
  , sitecode        INTEGER
  , location_code   INTEGER
  , job_no          INTEGER
  , product_code    INTEGER
  , product_name    VARCHAR2 (10)
  , qty_avl         INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE ms_principal
(
    prn_code   INTEGER
  , prn_name   VARCHAR2 (10)
);

CREATE TABLE tt_stkled
(
    cmp_code        INTEGER
  , prn_code        INTEGER
  , job_no          INTEGER
  , prn_date        DATE
  , qty_avl         INTEGER
  , sitecode        INTEGER
  , location_code   INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE ms_product
(
    prn_code       INTEGER
  , product_code   INTEGER
  , product_name   VARCHAR2 (10)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_jobdetails
AS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmp_jobdetails (
               cmp_code, prn_code, prn_name
             , sitecode, location_code, job_no
             , product_code, product_name, qty_avl
                )
        SELECT tt.cmp_code
             , tt.prn_code
             , mp.prn_name
             , tt.sitecode
             , tt.location_code
             , tt.job_no
             , ms.product_code
             , ms.product_name
             , tt.qty_avl
          FROM ms_principal mp
               JOIN tt_stkled tt ON (mp.prn_code = tt.prn_code)
               JOIN ms_product ms ON (ms.prn_code = mp.prn_code)
               JOIN tt_stkled tt ON (tt.prn_code = mp.prn_code);

    COMMIT;
END;
```